# LEFT JOIN Condition Error

Tags: database, join, db2, subquery, db2-luw

I created this stored procedure in **DB2** using **Toad For DB2.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE TEST_PROC 
BEGIN

  DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE_1(ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,col001 CHAR(36)) NOT LOGGED WITH REPLACE;
  DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE_2(ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,col001 CHAR(36)) NOT LOGGED WITH REPLACE;
  DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE_3(ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,col001 CHAR(36)) NOT LOGGED WITH REPLACE;

  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_1(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_1_ROW_1');
  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_1(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_1_ROW_2');
  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_1(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_1_ROW_3');
  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_1(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_1_ROW_4');

  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_2(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_2_ROW_1');
  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_2(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_2_ROW_2');
  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_2(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_2_ROW_3');

  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_3(col001) VALUES ('TABLE_3_ROW_1'); 

  BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_cursor CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR
      SELECT tmp.* FROM(
        SELECT id, col001  from SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_1
      )tmp
      Left join SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_2 tmp2 ON tmp2.id = tmp.id
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_3 t3 WHERE t3.ID = 2);
    OPEN temp_cursor;
  END;    
END;
```

But executing this stored procedure `Call TEST_PROC()` generates error.

> DB2 Database Error: ERROR [56098] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0727N  An error occurred during implicit system action type "5". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-338", SQLSTATE "42972" and message tokens "".  SQLSTATE=56098

It does not give any error, if I

- Change `Left Join` to `INNER JOIN`
- Remove this condition `AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_3 t3 WHERE t3.ID = 2)`

but these two are required.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You left join with `temp_table_2` yet do not select any of its values; 
You use `temp_table_3` in the left join `on` expression but it is not a participant in the join.  Please show us what the expected result set should be.

Comment: The error message means that the `ON` clause is invalid. According to [the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00338n.html) you cannot have a subquery in the `ON` clause. You'll have to find a way to rewrite your query.

Comment: @mustaccio  i moved `subquery` to `Where` section and it worked.

Comment: @mustaccio Can you add your comment as an answer? As always you are spot on.